# In Ruby, I have a Hash value containing a variable. How do I obtain its namespace?

Tags: ruby, hash, namespaces

I have a hash value containing a variable:

```
module Categories
  module Services
    PHOTOGRAPHY_VIDEO = "9115"
  end
end

hash = {"CatId" => Categories::Services::PHOTOGRAPHY_VIDEO}

puts(hash["CatId"]) # This returns "9115" but how do I get the "Services" category?
```

I want to ask Ruby for the namespace of the variable 'value' of 'CatId' equal to 'Services'. I want to do something like this:

```
def priced?
  (hash["CatId"]).unknown_method == Services
end
```

How do I obtain its namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Given a value such as '9115' there's no way (other than an exhaustive search, which would only be practical if there were a small number total) of knowing what constants have been set to a particular video.

If you need to get at this information, I'd rethink what data you store - the value for the CatId key could be something with more information in it (eg a struct containing both the id and a textual description)

Comment: Thank you. In order to learn programming I'm building an API for a website my wife uses often. gumtree.co.za So the values of the hash keys are set for me by what the website is looking for when I post an ad. So if I gave the key a more descriptive value I would have to rename it after checking it from the API user and before passing it to the website, I'm assuming that would not be best practice.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to store a separate map of category ids to their descriptions / namespaces

Comment: That can work, brilliant! I would still like to see a more elegant solution if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

The `Categories::Services::PHOTOGRAPHY_VIDEO` is only a constant in that class. Its value has no connection to the model (what you called namespace); it is just a string in this case. You can check the hash value against it again.

```
def priced?
  (hash["CatId"]) == Categories::Services::PHOTOGRAPHY_VIDEO
end
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help the new guy here, I can't get this code to run without "TypeError: can't convert String into Integer" but even if it did. There will be many constants under the Services 'model' and I need my code to do something if any of them are passed in.

Comment: Then you probably mixed up some number in that hash values. Try it to give that constant as a number, not as a string. Or use string where you put other values into that hash. Be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
"#{hash["CatId"]}".include? 'Services::'
```

update =>

Ohh, I got it now more clear

```
module Categories
  module Services
    PHOTOGRAPHY_VIDEO = "9115"
  end
end

hash = {"CatId" => "Categories::Services::PHOTOGRAPHY_VIDEO"}

eval hash["CatId"] # => "9155"
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, I really appreciate everyone trying to help. This is the most eloquent example of what I want to do but it doesn't work when I try it. Ruby 1.9.3 returns false when I run it while I need it to be true. Then when I substitute '9115' instead of 'Services::' your code returns true which means this is still just checking the value of the variable and not the variable itself.